# "on duplicate key update" all the non-key fields mentioned in the insert

Tags: mysql, query, primary-key, insert

How can I update the field values mentioned in the `insert` portion without listing them again in the `on duplicate key update` portion?

```
insert into tablename set keyname = 'keyvalue',
    fieldname = 'fieldvalue'
    . . .
    on duplicate key update
        updatecounter = updatecounter + 1
        fieldname = 'fieldvalue'
        . . .;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`VALUES(column)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values) function:

```
insert into tablename set keyname = 'keyvalue',
    fieldname = 'fieldvalue'
    . . .
    on duplicate key update
        updatecounter = updatecounter + 1,
        fieldname = VALUES(fieldname)
        . . .;
```

---

While the above method is still valid, it was deprecated in MySQL version 8.0.20 and subject to removal in the future. The new method to do this as explained in [MySQL docs: INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) is:

```
insert into tablename set keyname = 'keyvalue',
    fieldname = 'fieldvalue'
    . . .
    AS new        -- adding a table alias for the set
                  -- of values to be on inserted
    on duplicate key update
        updatecounter = updatecounter + 1,  -- refers to existing table value
        fieldname = new.fieldname           -- refers to above set
        . . .;
```

Comment: Yours is the correct syntax I was not paying attention. Yours is a +1 !!!

Comment: It's definitely no less verbose. However, it benefits from being much more maintainable since the literals only have to be specified once each. +1 and accepted.

Comment: The use of VALUES() to refer to the new column value is deprecated in MySQL 8.0.20, and is subject to removal in a future. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values

Comment: Thnx @Dr.DS I have a lot of answers that will need update :(

Answer (score 1):

You have one of two options:

### **OPTION # 1**

You may want to experiment by adding an additional UNIQUE KEY

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD UNIQUE KEY (keyname,fieldname);
```

Then try running your same UPDATE without `fieldname` like this

```
insert into tablename set keyname = 'keyvalue',
    fieldname = 'fieldvalue'
    . . .
    on duplicate key update
        updatecounter = updatecounter + 1
        . . .;
```

If that does not produce the desired behavior, then there is **OPTION 2**

### **OPTION # 2**

In terms of SQL synntax, you simply have no other other option

```
insert into tablename set keyname = 'keyvalue',
    fieldname = 'fieldvalue'
    . . .
    on duplicate key update
        updatecounter = updatecounter + 1
        fieldname = 'fieldvalue'
        . . .;
```

What you stated in the question is really all you can do

Comment: Option 1 had no effect. Option 2 (my original version) works, but is unpleasantly verbose. Thanks for your assistance.